# Google SERP shows ridiculously different product price

Tags: schema, google-product-search

`Hi,

Hope that somebody could take a look to my problem differently.

I have added schema for product and have price calculator on this page https://www.elegantepress.com/letterpress-business-cards/

Schema validator does not shows errors, but in google search page, in products line, the price in $ is doubled and multiplied by 100. Check out this image [Google SERP view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnnV3.jpg)

How such magic could appear? Is it any chance to fix it?`